# The roots of $e^{-x}-x^2+\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

After plotting in Mathematica the function $f(x)=e^{-x}-x^2+\cos x$, I realised that the transcendental equation 
$$e^{-x}-x^2+\cos(x)=0$$ 
has **only one root** somewhere near the real number $1$. You may check it with WolframAlpha. For me, that was not enough. I wanted to prove it theoretically, as far as the unique solution concerns, using calculus. So I did the following steps :

1. I proved that there is a root in the interval $[0,\pi]$. This is because $f(0)>0$ , $f(\pi)<0$  and $f$ is continous.
2. As $f'(x)=-e^{-x}-2x-\sin(x)<0$ for $x\ge0$ ,  $f$ is monotone so this root is unique there.
3. For $x\le-\ln(2)$ , we can easily show that $e^{-x}-x^2-1>0$ and so $f(x)=e^{-x}-x^2+\cos(x)>e^{-x}-x^2-1>0$ .

But how about the interval $(-\ln(2),0)$ ? How can we prove that $f(x)>0$ .

Thank you for any suggestions-hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for $x\in (-\ln(2),0)\subset(-1,0)\subset(-\pi/2,0)$,
$$f(x)=e^{-x}-x^2+\underbrace{\cos(x)}_{>0}> (1-x)-x^2=1+\underbrace{(-x)(1+x)}_{>0}> 1$$
where we used the inequality $e^t\geq 1+t$ which holds for all real $t$.

Answer (score 1):

One first analysis is to check that $$f(x) = e^{-x}-x^2 \in [-1,1]$$ This is a requirement for $\cos(x)$ to be able to "reach" it, since range of $\cos(x)$ is $[-1,1]$.

The derivative of $f$ is $f'(x) = -e^{-x} -2x$, which never attains $0$.This should be easy for the curious student to show with some inequalities from first calculus course.

So it is always negative, meaning $f$ is a strictly declining function. So it has exactly 1 solution for each of -1 and 1.

We can now narrow down the area of possible zeroes of the initial function to numerically between $x\in [0,1.2]$. If it is not narrow enough, we will probably need to chase cos closer than upper and lower bounds of $\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please specify the domain of function $h$?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "need to chase cos closer than upper and lower bounds of ±1" ?

Comment: What is $h$? I don't mention this function. If the answer helps you, feel free to upvote it. We use an estimation of cos and the fact that $a+b$ can not be 0 if $a$ is within [1,-1] but $b$ is not. If $b$ is outside that interval then there is no way a number within the same interval can add up to 0 with it.

Comment: If you can see, I edited a bit your answer, because there was some conflict concerning the symbol $f$ with the question...

Comment: You edited your question and changed notation *after* you got an answer. This is not optimal. I still can not see any $h$ in the answer.

Comment: I have not changed my question, I proposed an edit to your answer...

Comment: So for your $f$ what is the domain ?

Comment: The point is that we show that $f$ is strictly decreasing everywhere, and so it can only take values $-1$ and $1$ once each. So there is a limited set of $x$ in between these two where we can have equality, because any point with equality in the original expression $f$ needs to take opposite value of whatever value $\cos$ takes. And we know that $\cos$ is limited to take values $\in [-1,1]$.